# Converting PDF and adding a Front Page, footer and watermark

Tags: php, pdf, document, fpdf, libreoffice

My current application requires me to convert a document (doc, excel, ppt, image, etc) to PDF. It also requires to add a front page with several information (variable) and add footer to converted document. It may also require to add a text or a logo image as an watermark.

I have been able to convert document to PDF using LibreOffice. I generated a static pdf and I could merge it with converted document using **[PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)**

But I need to generate front page dynamically because for each document, some information will change. I thought of using FPDF to generate front page, convert with libreoffice and merge it using PDFtk. But again, it will require adding footer and possibly a watermark. I think watermark can be done by PDFtk. And footer can be generated by FPDF.

So whole process will look like this:

- Created Front page with FPDF and save pdf
- Convert Doc to PDF with LibreOffice
- Add footer to converted PDF and store with FPDF
- Generate PDF with watermark using FPDF (possibly)
- Combine above three pdf using PDFtk

I guess I am doing too much of processing. Is there a simpler way to achieve this? Are there any alternatives to achieve this with lesser resources / third party apps/lib ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decrease the number of different things that I need to do, I will simply use the FPDI library.

So what I am going to now is,

- Convert the document into PDF format
- Create Front Page using FPDI (which extends TCPDF and uses it's function)
- Then I will import the converted document using FPDI ' s import feature
- I will also add watermark and footer same time

So I will ultimately eliminate the use of PDFtk and reduce the number of libraries used and different activities required to be done separately.

These thing will be done in two activities only :

1. Convert to PDF with LibreOffice and
2. Add a front page, import and add footer and watermark with FPDI

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to commercially licenced software, [PDFLib+PDI](http://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/pdflib-pdi/) will handle all the tasks you require (after conversion to PDF). It runs natively on most server environments with generally very good performance.

Comment: Yes, I am open to commercial products, provided cost is not too high. This product seems helpful but question is, how much boost in processing am I going to get after spending that much money.

Comment: As for rendering simple text, it shouldn't make any difference, but in my experience it is extremely fast also when rendering graphics (both vector and other), merging and doing operations on heavy documents. I suppose you could try the free version (PDFlib Lite) to do some simple performance benchmarking on your system...

Comment: As I have mentioned in question, most of the processing will be putting a front page, putting a footer text and maybe putting a stamp or watermark. I will try this thing.

Answer (score 0):

The Library I have used to handle PDFs with PHP is [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). It's open source, you can use HTML to style the PDF (a subset of HTML anyway), handle things like pages. I believe you should be able to perform the functions you require all in TCPDF.

To handle manipulations to images, which you may need for watermarking etc, I used [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) which provides numerous functions for manipulating images. If you require some more complex image manipulations, you may also want to look at [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

All of this should simplify your workflow, and allow you to do most of what you require directly in PHP and HTML.

Comment: Just not sure how TCPDF will reduce the total processing that I'll need to do.

Comment: You should be able to do what you are asking all with TCPDF apart from the converting the doc files

Comment: Can I import existing document? Or I have to use FPDI for that?

Comment: I can't remember, there is plenty of documentation on the TCPDF site. It's a little difficult to navigate, but the documentation is good.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it yet, but [DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) looks like a nice project.
I was using [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default) before, but it's not updated anymore so moving on.

If you're using such libraries, just make HTML templates (moreover, DomPDF supports PHP execution inside html templates) and have fun ;)

Comment: But again, for importing PDF, I have to rely on something else, no?

Comment: TCPDF is your boy for that (that's why I like HTML2PDF too, it's built on top of TCPDF)

Comment: Isn't that under development?

Comment: Indeed, it is...since 2011. I guess you can't count on it, sorry for misleading :/

FPDI is the good choice then, as you said.